# Windows network missing from Nautilus after reboot

Tags: 12.04, networking, windows

When I first installed Ubuntu 12.04, my Nautilus browser included a "Browse Network" section which included icons for the two Windows 7 PCs in the household. Since then, nothing has changed on either the Windows or the Ubuntu end, with the exclusion of me installing google chrome off a .deb file.

Now, the two PCs are missing from the Nautilus "Browse Network" section. In their place is a generic "Windows Network" icon. When clicked, after a long delay, it sends back an error message:

> Unable to mount location
>   DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Mountpoint Already registered

Having Ubuntu provisioned on this laptop for less than 72 hours, it was a surprise to see it automatically provision the windows network. I seem to recall Ubuntu a few years ago requiring me to install Samba and do some pretty heavy (for me) configuration; and still the support was pretty dodgy.

Does Ubuntu just come with Samba installed and configured out of the box, or was something else going on? What could have caused the PC discovery to fail, and what should I do to remedy it?

Answer (score 1):

Strangly- a .desktop file was fowling up my Nautilus. I had created a .desktop file with the command `gksu nautilus` and added it to the unity launcher. Although I wasn't running nautilus through the .desktop file, the window title (which I had imaginatively called `Nautilus as Root` in the .desktop) was suggesting it was being run. I deleted the .desktop file, which prevented me from opening nautilus at all (even from terminal `nautilus`). A reboot solved this, and my nautilus network discovery is back online (with some other problems - opening a new question).